# Connect iPhone app to access point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wifi

I'm trying to create an app that scans available wifi networks and if it is available accesses.

It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5 it is possible to scan the network list using private API on a jailbroken device only. This [blog post](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) states the following:

> Last year Apple has blocked wifi scanners from App Store, however till
>   iOS5 it was still available for private usage via WiFiManager bundle.
>
> In iOS5, WifiManager bundle no more exists however 80211 functions are
>   still available via IPConfiguration bundle.

The API you linked provides an open-source tool Stumbler which seems like something you were seeking. The tool is claimed to work under iOS 5.